# JSON extractorion issue

Tags: json, expression, extractor

I have a JSON like below and I want to extract ID using a username by json extractor expression.
I am using $..username , it give me all the username. what I need is that I pass username = Albert and it give me id = 1234

is that doable ?

```
  {         "data": [
       {
            "country": 111,
            "role": {
                "name": "Admin",
                "id": 1
            },
            "last_name": "mir",
            "id": 1234,
            "first_name": "Albert",
            "username": "Albert.mir",
        },
               {
            "country": 112,
            "role": {
                "name": "Admin",
                "id": 1
            },
            "last_name": "marr",
            "id": 12345,
            "first_name": "Albbert",
            "username": "Albbert.mir",
        }

        ]
        }
```

Comment: Do you mean JsonPATH expression?

Comment: your JSON is invalid due to extra commas

Answer (score 0):

.. is recursive descent in JsonPath

? is filter

@ current object

Thus,

```
 $..[?(@.username='Albert')].id
```

Note that JSON that you provides is invalid, and have no username Albert in it (only Albert.mir)
Read a good intro into JsonPATH, it is not that difficult to master https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Comment: Thanks, I have tried same, but with single quotes and it worked.